# mysql 5.5 repartition

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, partitioning

With MySQL 5.5, I want to change the partitioning scheme of a very large InnoDB table from "hash" to "range". Can I do it while the table is accepting DML? If not, what is the best-practice work-around?

Thanks!

Comment: *Can I do it while the table is accepting DML?* No. Repartitioning cannot be in-place. *what is the best-practice work-around?* Copy table data to new structure, then replace the table by rename. Autoincrement not-autoutilizing forbid + autoassigned timestamp needed to alter the data changed during copy process.

Answer (score 0):

There probably is no way to change the partitioning without taking downtime.  If you can block just writes, then this would allow concurrent reads:

```
disable writes (not via SQL)
CREATE TABLE new ... PARTITION BY RANGE ...
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT * FROM real;   --  probably wise to do in chunks
test new table
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;  -- Fast and atomic
DROP TABLE old;
enable writes
```

*But* -- Before embarking on the rebuild, please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (both by-hash and by-range) *and* the important `SELECTs`.  Also, explain the purpose of using Partitioning.  It *may* be that Partitioning, even by-range, is not worth doing.  (In my experience by-hash is useless.)

My comments on partitioning (perhaps relevant):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: Your workaround is promising, thanks. Range-date partitioning is necessary because most queries go by date range so pruning will clearly work.

Comment: @GID - Pruning may "work", but it may not add any performance benefit.  Be aware that all the indexes should be rethought when changing to/from Partitioning.